# Why does submitting a Task to an Executor result in a Future<*>

Tags: kotlin, javafx, java.util.concurrent

Let's say I have a `Task` class

```
class Abc : Task<Foo>() {
   ...
}
```

and a `Callable` class

```
class Def : Task<Foo>() {
   ...
}
```

When I try to run the `Callable` and get a future `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(Def())` I get a `Future<Foo>`. However, when I try to run the Task `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(Abc())` I get `Future<*>`.

How can I get a future of the correct type using the JavaFX `Task` class? Or should I be doing something entirely different?

Comment: The code in your question is not Java. Is it Kotlin? Also, it appears that both classes `Abc` and `Def` extend class `Task`. Did you mean to write that class `Def` implements `Callable` (rather than extends `Task`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Task` class (assuming it is [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) class) only implements the `Runnable` interface for the `ExecutorService`. Because the `Runnable` has no return type the returned `Future` can't have a result type. For the `Callable` interface the `ExecutorService` has a separate method that returns a future using the return type of the `Callable` instance.

What you could to is to create a callable instance that executes the task impelementation instead of passing the task instance to the `ExecutorService`

Comment: If you want to control the thread pool for a Task, then you should use Service to generate them.